# Merge 2 components using reactjs (or simple css ?)

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to put little frames upon a photo (the framas are positionned on the faces). The problem is I need them to bleong to each other. Like if I move the photo, the frames have to move with it.

Everyhting (photo, frame position) is dynamic, coming from a json file. At first, I've tried to use Material ui with a component for the photo and another one for the frame. I'm now trying to use pure css (also with a photo component which contains the CadreCss component), but of course it's still not working.

CadreCSS.js file

```
class CadreCSS extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Datas:DataCadres
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {Datas} = this.state;

        return(
            <div>
                {
                    Datas.map(data=>(
                        <div>
                            <div className= "frame" style ={{top:data.y+"px", left:data.x+"px"}} ></div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

css file

```
.frame{
    border: 3px solid red;
    width: 110px;
    height:110px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}

.imageTest{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Now, when I move the photo, the frames don't move with it. I begin to wonder if the problem would be that I'm supposed to place the frames proportionnaly to the photo. Either way, I don't know how to do that.. 
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: This is incomplete code. Do you have a click handler? Where are you placing .imageTest element? Try making a basic project on codepen.

Comment: You're right, I forgot I'm not using imageTest.  I finally went through it by adding a div class container to surround the whole thing.

Comment: Firstly I would ask if .imageTest is a child of .frame because your code is still incomplete. Where and how are you adding .imageTest ? What you mean by "move the photo" ? There must be some js involved? Where is it? You can easily recreate a react example of your problem in https://codesandbox.io .